# collection_select doesn't call first value_method on collection member

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = %i[admin moderator author]
end
```

Sign up form (initially generated by devise gem):

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <!-- other fields -->
  <div>
    <%= f.label :role %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, :humanize) %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

When try to render this form I get error message:

```
undefined method `humanize' for :admin:Symbol
```

Why first method `:to_s` wasn't called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why first method :to_s wasn't called?

It was called on `value_method` of `collection_select`, but not on a `label_method`. Take a look at [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select).

> undefined method `humanize' for :admin:Symbol

`humanize` is defined for `string` only. Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:role, User::ROLES, :to_s, lambda{|i| i.to_s.humanize}) %>
```

Comment: Why in the second argument you set collection ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit please have a look at documentation link I provided. The trick here is that `collection_select` called on form's object `f`, so the first argument (object) is already filled.
As of lambda, you should call `humanize` on strings, not symbols. `value_method` and `text_method` accept accept any object which responds to `call` (e.g., procs and lambdas)

Comment: @ArupRakshit could you please give it a try? This works like a charm in my production code (although I use `simple_form` there).

Comment: I can see in the [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) that, *The value returned from calling **method** on the instance **object** will be selected.* But without *method* it will also work, you are saying.

Comment: @ArupRakshit the first argument here is `:role` which is **method**. And the instance **object** is **f**, which `collection_select` was called on.

Comment: First of all, I understand that `humanize` is for String. Doc says that `value_method` and `text_method` are methods to be called on each member of collection. So, why `:to_s` is not called?

Comment: @mef_ do you realize that `value_method` and `text_method` are not chained one by one and should instead return two different outputs?